# Use SQL (Like) when have Multiple (WHERE)

Tags: php, sql-like

How Can i add (Like) to this Code When we have some WHERE item :

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE zone_id='$zone' and category_id='$category' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Comment: where do you want add like, for which column?

Comment: @vSugumar for name column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `like` before the `ORDER BY`. I added `x like y`. It is no differnt from adding `x=y` similar to the two equivalent statements you already had.

```
"SELECT * FROM test WHERE zone_id='$zone' and category_id='$category' and x like y ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Comment: Does your statement work if you do not add the `$name` section? If so, you should print out the `$name` variable and check to see what value it is holding. Also, try printing out your query before sending it to the database.
`$query = "Select * FROM test where  X=Y etc"; print $query; $result = $this->db->query($query);`

Comment: Thanks my friend !